# Set timezone in mysql not working on datetime?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a datetime colum named `creation_date`.
when im using the SET time zone its still showing the same result.
What am I doing wrong?

My Code:

```
SET time_zone = "America/Los_Angeles";
SELECT *  FROM `enswitch_mobile_users` WHERE `creation_date` > '2013-06-02 00:00:00';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime` mysql data type doesn't care of `time_zone` directive. Only `timestamp` does

So the solution - change the type to `timestamp`

Comment: will it affect this colum data? I mean if im changing it from datetime to timestamp. is it safe? since I theres alot of records in this table. and I can't allow myself to lose the `creation_date` time

Comment: I would say it's safe but if you don't trust me - just create another column and use `UPDATE table SET newcol = oldcol`

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would stick with `DATETIME` and always use [`UTC_TIMESTMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp) instead of `NOW()` or similar. Then when reading your date from the database, you can convert it with [`CONVERT_TZ()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) as needed.

Comment: So instead of doing it once you would prefer to take care about it manually in **every** single query?

Comment: If you are operating an international website, you have to do it anyway. If you don't, you usually do not have to care about timezones anyway.

Comment: if you use timestamp - you just specify `SET time_zone` once after connect and everything else is done by mysql automagically, so "you have to do it anyway" isn't entirely true

Comment: Using `TIMESTAMP` is not as flexible as `DATETIME` and it has to be converted to `DATETIME` with `FROM_UNIXTIME()` when using proper date/time functions. So it is a little overhead with both solutions. However, you can always create a user defined function for handling the timezone conversion when using `DATETIME` more easily.

Comment: "and it has to be converted to DATETIME with FROM_UNIXTIME() when using proper date/time functions" --- I'm sure you're confusing `timestamp` type with something else (it's identical to `datetime` but with timezones handling). Please refresh your knowledge by reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Comment: "it's identical to datetime but with timezones handling". No it's not, e.g. it is limited in the date range it may store.

Comment: there are differences indeed, but not from performance perspective (as you mentioned in "it has to be converted")

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in the [MySQL documentation on date and time types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for
>   storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
>   (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)